# Split a user input

Tags: python, split

I'd like to take a user input about the delimiter and use it to split the data.
I thought the line of code should look something like this:

```
my_delimiter = raw_input("write down the delimiter of your file(e.g. ','): ")
for line in file:
    line2 = line.split(my_delimiter)
    print line2
    main_data.append(line2)
```

Then my sample input should be like

> write down the delimiter of your file(e.g. ','): '\t'

and the output should be like

```
['age', 'prescript', 'astigmatic', 'tearRate\n'] 
['young', 'myope', 'no', 'reduced', 'no lenses\n']
```

but it remains the same.
But it doesn't work. it is not delimited by tab or comma as I hope it to be.
Please help me figure this out.

Comment: Can you please fix indentation issues, and let us know a sample input you are giving for which its not working and the expected output?

Comment: Are there actual `\t` in your file?

Comment: Are you asking us to help with a problem in your input data?

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: What is in your file?

Comment: If the user enters `\t`, it will be interpreted as "backslash" and "t", not "tab character". The user needs to input an actual tab if he wants to split on tabs.

Comment: Post a few lines of your input data/or a sample

Comment: You also shouldn't add quotes to the string you input

Comment: If it is not delimited by tab or comma as you hope it to be, you have to format it properly first or your script won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are entering the values '\t' in the raw_input it turns them into the str '\t' which has 2 ascii characters. It doesn't turn '\t' into the tab character as you want.
if for example, you know that you are going to get the input '\t' and you want to turn it into the tab character

```
my_delimiter = my_delimiter.replace('\\t', '\t')
```

this will change it into actual tab character. But then you would have to do it to all escaped characters like '\r' and '\n' and so on. What you should do is ask for the ascii values of the characters separated by a ','. In this case ask for the ascii value of '9' and turn it into int() and then into chr() and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

If the user inputs `\t` it will be coming as `\\t` the backslash would be escaped and it can be interpreted as `blackslash t` not `tab` character.

To input the `tab` character (`\t`) , you should press the tab key and then press `return` key.

Example -

```
>>> raw_input("Please input :")
Please input :\t
'\\t'
>>> raw_input("Please input :")
Please input :  
'\t'
```

Note , in the second case, I pressed tab key and then return key.

Answer (score 0):

You may do this by using python's re module:

```
import re
my_delimiter = ",|\.|:"
my_txt = "this is, just a simple: txt"
delimited_list = re.split(my_delimiter, my_txt)
print delimited_list
```

the result will be like:

```
print delimited_list
['this is', ' just a simple', ' txt']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d = r'\t'  # That's actual input you've got from user
>>> d
'\\t'
>>> d.decode('unicode-escape')  # That's one you really want to use
u'\t'
```